# Magento 2: Clicking on menu always goes to index dashboard page

Tags: extensions, magento-2.0, menu

I have created a submenu in Magento 2 back end and want to show grid on clicking on it.

app\code\Tutorial\SimpleNews\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

 config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 ="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
  <menu>
    <add id="Tutorial_SimpleNews::main_menu" title="Simple News" 
        module="Tutorial_SimpleNews" sortOrder="20" 
        resource="Tutorial_SimpleNews::simplenews" />
    <add id="Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage_news" title="Manage News" 
        module="Tutorial_SimpleNews" sortOrder="2" parent="Tutorial_SimpleNews::main_menu" 
        action="simplenews/news/index" resource="Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage_news" />
 </menu>
</config>
```

app\code\Tutorial\SimpleNews\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/
 Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
 <router id="admin">
    <route id="simplenews" frontName="simplenews">
        <module name="Tutorial_SimpleNews" />
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

app\code\Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\News\Index.php

```
 <?php

 namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News;

 use Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News;

 class Index extends News
 {
 public function execute()
 {
   if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax')) {
        $this->_forward('grid');
        return;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Tutorial_SimpleNews::main_menu');
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Simple News'));

    return $resultPage;
 }
 }
```

app\code\Tutorial\SimpleNews\view\adminhtml\layout\simplenews_news_grid.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

  <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/
  Framework/View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
  <update handle="formkey"/>
  <update handle="simplenews_news_grid_block"/>
   <container name="root">
      <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container" 
        name="tutorial_simplenews_news.grid.container" 
        template="Magento_Backend::widget/grid/container/empty.phtml"/>
   </container>
  </layout>
```

When ever I click on submenu "Manage News" it redirects to admin dashboard instead of grid section created by me.

Here is the url I followed:

First Part: http://www.mage-world.com/blog/adding-new-menu-item-in-magento-2-custom-module.html

Second Part: http://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-1.html

Please help me.

Comment: have you created `news/index` controller?

Comment: also add code of your layout file with complete directory and name of file

Comment: @chirag Yes I have create new/index controller. See my updated question